# regex extracting from string into 2 groups

Tags: regex

given a string with legth of 10
ex: 0002312577
I need to return  two groups:
group 1 should be the entire string
group 2 just one number >0 , could be any number from the string

How to do this ? Tried for several hours with no luck,should be simple. This is what i've tried.

```
([0-9]{10,10})([1-9]{1,1})
```

i have to program a industrial machine that takes regex as input
Thank you

Comment: Try [`^((?=[0-9]{10}$)[0-9]*?([1-9])[0-9]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/GULQQ1/1).

Comment: Is length 10 guaranteed? Or has the regex to also validate that it is a string of length 10? Your regex can only match if the string has a length of 11. Change {10,10} to {9,9} and then fill extract \1\2 into one variable and \2 in the second variable. Your regex assumes that the last digit will always be non-zero. Is that valid? Or could a correct string have a "0" in the last place. You might want to give more sample input with accompanying desired match/non-match. Which regex flavor are you using? E.g. sed, awk, perl, ...

Comment: `(\d*([1-9])\d*)` should do it, without constraining input length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, this should do it:

```
^(?=0*([1-9]))([0-9]{10})$
```

It will match and capture a string of 10 digits, and capture the first non-zero digit in a second group.

**Explanation**

`^` ensures we start matching at the start of the string

`(?=0*([1-9]))` looks ahead (without consuming) to the first non-zero digit and captures it

`([0-9]{10})` ensures the entire string is 10 digits and captures it

---

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/W1vb5U/3).

Comment: Your "capture the first non-zero digit in a second group" explanation is not quite right, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/W1vb5U/2).

Comment: Good point, updated to only match an actual non-zero (presuming this is intended)

Comment: Thank you  and @WiktorStribiżew  both solution have worked for me. Really helped me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with 2 groups as required : `((0|\d){9}[1-9])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BIbJuQ/3)

And another one with only one group matching number > 0 : `(0|\d){9}[1-9]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BIbJuQ/4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems it fails if the last digit is 0 .eX 0002312570